# raspi3 qemu wont reboot

Tags: qemu, reboot

I finally got raspian to boot in quem by following these instructions.

https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/tree/master/native-emulation

The only problem is that I can't figure out how to make the machine reboot. If I type sudo reboot now, it just shuts down and does not start back up.  The update process that I am trying to test specifically relies on rebooting and then checking that the machine has booted back into a valid state.

Comment: why does the update process rely on a specific type of boot?

Comment: In real life I am updating remote devices that I nobody will have access to, but maybe I can fake it in qemu with a shutdown.  Part of the trouble is that I would like to test on a cluster of devices so that seems like a lot to hack if I could just get rebooting to work instead.